# OpenMP exclusive scan reduction segfaults as N increases

Tags: openmp

I have the following code where I am performing an exclusive scan. This code works up until N gets large enough. On my machine it started to segfault when N=10000000. What exactly is the issue here?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

auto main(int argc, char *argv[]) -> int {
  int N = std::stoi(argv[1]);
  int x = 0;

  std::vector<int> a(N);
  std::vector<int> b(N);

  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    a[i] = i + 1;
  }

#pragma omp parallel for reduction(inscan, + : x)
  for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    b[i] = x;
#pragma omp scan exclusive(x)
    x += a[i];
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Getting rid of the parallel immediately seems to fix the problem. I am guessing the issue some sort of memory constraint when performing the reduction?

Looking at other library implementations of exclusive scan using the OpenMP as a backend the code is quite different.

I have tried this on a machine Homebrew clang version 16.0.3 on an M1 Air. I have also tried it on a Power9 CPU using the XL compiler 16.1.1 running Red Hat Enterprise Linux (RHEL) version 8.2 and I am getting the same issue.

Comment: Not sure this is relevant, but with an `N` that large, you are overflowing your `b`s and your `x`. Also, please, what are your compiler and OS?

Comment: @Gilles I have editing my question to include the compiler and OS